# Several times request to load plugins when sending one request

Tags: http, logging

When we sending 1 request to load any page (Home, Single or etc), WordPress running more than several times.

For example you can adding the below code in the main plugin file or `functions.php` in current theme and you can see the log file!

```
file_put_contents('log', print_r($_REQUEST, 1), FILE_APPEND);
```

I need a solution to fix/skip this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might well be, but that's alright. There might be redirects happening, and those will result in multiple requests.
The WordPress-Cron System relies on AJAX-requests, those will also show up in the log.
If you load any resources (images, scripts, stylesheets) that do not exist, WordPress will be loaded and handle the 404, resulting in more requests (and log entries).

Unless you're seeing a large number of requests per page view, it's probably fine. If you do, use your browser's developer tools to see what requests it is sending and why.

Comment: I think sometimes the hooks can be effective to this issue.

Comment: Wordpress action hooks don't/shouldn't result in additional requests unless some plugin is doing very strange things.